# Take -ing as adverb

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I am a fan of [Devil May Cry](http://devilmaycry.com/).

In Devil May Cry 4, the highest rank for fighting is called *smokin' sick style*.

Here, it seems that *smokin'* is used as an adverb.

I guess it is derived from the usage of the *f* word.

Is it acceptable to take an *-ing* word as an adverb, which is commonly used as an adjective? Are there any other examples?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It it's not uncommon to see such words used as adverbs. The word *fucking* and its many euphemisms furnish us the prime examples of this.

> This is fucking great.
>
> Don't be so frickin' stupid.
>
> Learn to bleepin' drive!

But there are other examples that don't involve profanity:

> It's boiling hot outside.
>
> Put on a jacket. It's freezing cold.

These use cases, as you see, all involve intensifiers of some kind. That's how *smokin'* works in your example. All the example words may be used as adjectives as well.

Answer (score 1):

Smoking is a normal adjective meaning great. 
Smokin' is just a way to make it more *slangy*, like *friggin'* and *smokin' hot babe* for example

I even saw this:

> Smoking or Smokin', a slang term for
>   overtaking other vehicles in
>   motor-sport events